# new AsyncTask<ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC>, what goes where?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

regarding `AsyncTask<ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC>` parameters, I am always confused about which Object effects what.

One effects my `doInBackGround` return type, one effects my `doInBackGround` input type, and the third object effects something else.

When I am changing what kind of things I want to send in and return, this gets very confusing.

What does `ObjectA` effect

What does `ObjectB` effect

What does `ObjectC` effect

(ignore possible misuse of effect/affect)

Comment: Hover over AsyncTask in Eclipse , and you will see a full page of explanation with an example, and breakdowns of all 3 params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
ObjectA - doInBackground();

ObjectB - progress indicator: publishProgress(), etc

ObjectC - onPostExecute(), what doInBackground() must return
```

To actually quote:

> AsyncTask's generic types
>
> ---
>
> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> 1.Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
>
> 2.Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
>
> 3.Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
>
> Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type
>   as unused, simply use the type [**Void**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Void.html):

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation before asking such kind of questions: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

It says:

> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> 1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
> 2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
> 3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
>
> Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type
>   as unused, simply use the type Void.